# Maintain Unicode characters while running external programs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, unicode

I am trying to run an external command by passing it Lazy Text in stdin. The text contains unicode characters but they are not showing up correctly in the output. Below is a minimal example with the external command as `tee`. For shell utilities I am using the [shellmate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shellmate-0.3.2/docs/Control-Shell.html) package

```
Sh.shell $ do
  hStdIn <- Sh.getStdIn
  hStdOut <- Sh.getStdOut
  Sh.liftIO $ IO.hSetEncoding hStdIn IO.utf8
  Sh.liftIO $ IO.hSetEncoding hStdOut IO.utf8
  Sh.echo_ someText Sh.|> Sh.run "tee" []
```

If `someText` is `×` in the output I see `�`.

I also tried converting the text to `ByteString` using the [`encodeUtf8`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Encoding.html#v:encodeUtf8) function and then converting to String.

```
import Data.ByteString.UTF8 (toString, fromString)
import Data.Text.Encoding (encodeUtf8, decodeUtf8)
import Data.Text.Lazy (toStrict, fromStrict)

Sh.echo_ (toString . encodeUtf8 . toStrict (someText))
  Sh.|> Sh.run "tee" []
```

and decoding as

```
(fromStrict . decodeUtf8 . fromString) c
```

**Edit:**

I was unable to fix this with shellmate, so started using `System.Process`.

```
import qualified System.IO as IO

(Just inp, Just outp, _, phandle) <-
  P.createProcess
    (P.proc "tee" [])
    { P.std_out = P.CreatePipe, P.std_in = P.CreatePipe }

IO.hSetEncoding inp IO.utf8
IO.hSetEncoding outp IO.utf8

IO.hPutStr inp someText

outputText <- IO.hGetContents outp
```

Comment: Is your terminal ok, that is, can you `echo ×` and get correct output?

Comment: Try "print someText". This will print the escaped version so you can see what code points are in it. Unicode from outside the ASCII set will show up as backslashed octal codes. E.g. print "ê" will emit "\234".

Comment: Yes, `echo ×` work on my terminal and `print "×"` in GHCi prints `"\215"` which is correct I suppose.